# script to get average based on timestamps

Tags: unix, file, scripting

I have two fields in my text file which are

```
timestamp  number
```

The format of timestamp is hh:mm:ss.mmm

some sample records are

18:31:48.345   0.00345

18:31:49.153   0.00123

18.32:23.399   0.33456

I want to print out averages of records which are no more than 30 second apart. what is a good and fast way of doing it

Comment: Does it have to be a bash script? A Python script would be quite easy..

Comment: It can be a python script too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point in awk. I know you can optimize code better.

```
count == 0 { startTime = timeToSeconds($1) }
{   currentTime = timeToSeconds($1)
    elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime
    if (elapsedTime > 30.0) {
        calculateAverage()
        startTime = timeToSeconds($1)
    }
    print
    sum += $2
    count++
}
END { calculateAverage() }
function timeToSeconds(timeString) {
    # Convert a time string to number of seconds
    split(timeString, tokens, ":")
    seconds = tokens[1]*3600.0 + tokens[2]*60.0 + tokens[3]
    return seconds
}
function calculateAverage() {
    # Use & modify global vars: count, sum
    average = sum / count
    printf "Average: %.4g\n\n", average
    sum = 0.0; count = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using some scripting language that has built-in date/time 'operations'. For instance, in Ruby you could easily do:

```
require 'time'

t,n = gets.chomp.split(/\s+/)
ts1 = Time.parse(t)

# ...

t,n = gets.chomp.split(/\s+/)
ts2 = Time.parse(t)
```

Which now allows you to do things like:

```
diff = ts2 - ts1
if diff > 30
   # difference is greater than 30 seconds
end
```

Ruby `Time` objects can be used in context (float, int, String, etc) so it is trivial to start doing calculations as if the parsed dates are actually numeric values.